# how to handle pretty large response json request

Tags: android, json, http, get, buffer

I'm trying to do an async http get request to an API.
It does work actually but i can't figure out how to receive all the data i should get.

Here is the code :

```
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("API?access_token=" + this._request.getToken());
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null) {
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.i("infos", responseBody);
            }
            else{
                Log.i("infos", "entity is null");
            }
```

my Json looks like this :

```
ShoppingItem: {
 id: "2"
 shopping_item_category_id: "44"
 name: "Nuggets de poulet"
 description: ""
 created: "2014-02-05 17:34:26"
 modified: "2014-02-05 17:34:26"
}
```

I should get more or less a hundred like that one but i get 13 whatever i'm doing and the last one is not even full ...

To Parse the json i'm using Gson but for the moment it doesn't really matter ..

Would you have a solution for me ?
Thanks !! :)

Comment: Are you sure its not server fault? On windows you can use fiddler to setup proxy and look into what server is returning exactly.

Comment: i'm a hundred % sure .. i tested the server using Advances Rest Client Extention on Chrome and it does work ...